# Write file to Linux Application data directory

Tags: c++, qt, file, ubuntu

I need to write files to the Application Data directory of the application that I'm designing. Im developing under Ubuntu using Qt. The following snippet shows my write function:

```
FileOperations::Error FileOperations::saveUsage(SensorIdentification sensorID, QList<UsageListModel::Usage> &usageList)
{
    QString fileName(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation));
    fileName.append("/");
    fileName.append("testnaam");
    fileName.append(FILE_EXTENSION);

    this->sensorID = sensorID;
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        return Error::FileNotOpen;
    }

    QDataStream out(&file);

    out << sensorID;
    for(int i = 0; i < usageList.size(); i++)
        out << usageList.at(i).date << usageList.at(i).totalSteps << usageList.at(i).wearTime;
    if(file.size())
    {
        file.close();
        return Error::NoError;
    }
    else
    {
        file.close();
        return Error::WritingToFileFailed;
    }
}
```

The fileName after the appends is: `"/home/jan/.local/share/Foo/Bar With Spaces/testnaam.liv"`
For some reason I cant write a file in that directory. It does work correctly when i write to the users documents folder. Why cant i write to the appdata folder?

Comment: does this directory exists? QFile will not create missing directory

Comment: Yes the directory exists. I also chmodded the directory like this: u=rw

Comment: also: define "can't write" - which error does your function report etc. Or does it finish without error but file is empty etc.

Comment: It returns at Error::FileNotOpen. Sorry for not being specific

Comment: What `file.errorString()` returns?

Comment: Good idea, it returns permission denied. So, how should I set the permissions?

Comment: `u=rwx` is the correct permission for the directory - you need `x` to make the directory accessible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought x stands for execute, didn't know it also had something to do with permissions for directories.